# missing [ at start message send expression

Tags: ios, xcode

What is the problem with this code:

```
NSError *error = nil;

[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:@"<span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Times; font-size: small;">IAPNoob01</span>" andServiceName:kStoredData error:&error];
```

The error is:

The problem: missing [ at start message send expression

Comment: That's kind of weird a user name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes in the string.

```
NSError *error = nil;

[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:@"<span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"font-family:Times;
    font-size: small;\">IAPNoob01</span>"
    andServiceName:kStoredData
    error:&error];
```

Comment: @Alessandro no. Sonething in your code rises that error. The sample I wrote is flawless. (A compiler doesn't know where the cause of the syntax error is - it might be slightly earlier than the place it signals it to be.)

Comment: OH, I understand. Xcode added a space between the code automatically!!